# php fetch_assoc skip empty results

Tags: php

When echoing the results from fetch_assoc I wold like to skip the empty (NULL) results.
My code now is:

```
while ($rowsoft = $resultsoft->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<table class='swtable' cellspacing='0' summary='Software table'>
<tbody>
<tr><td class='software_up'><a class='sw' href='software.php?id=" . $rowsoft['id'] . "'>" . $rowsoft['title'] . "</a></td></tr>
<tr><td class='software'><div class='tags'>Tags: </div><a class='tags' href='#'>" . $rowsoft['tag_1'] . "</a>
<a class='tags' href='#'>" . $rowsoft['tag_2'] . "</a><a class='tags' href='#'>" . $rowsoft['tag_3'] . "</a></td></tr>
}
```

But not always there is a result for $rowsoft['tag_1'] or $rowsoft['tag_2'] or $rowsoft['tag_3'].
How can I change the echoing inside fetch_assoc() so that it works only if there is a result?
Or should I use foreach or something else?

Thank you

Comment: Why not exclude them in the sql query

Comment: Excluding them from the SQL is easy, but then for example <a class='tags' href='#'>... still will be echoed. I do not want it to be echoed if there is no SQL result

Comment: If you solved the issue please don't append *"solved"* to the title of the question, but consider [accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/224130) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it by changing the sql:

```
select
...    
    (select concat('<a href=\'#\' class=\'tags\'>',t.tag_bg,'</a>') from tags t where t.id=s.tag1) tag_1,
    (select concat('<a href=\'#\' class=\'tags\'>',t.tag_bg,'</a>') from tags t where t.id=s.tag2) tag_2,
    (select concat('<a href=\'#\' class=\'tags\'>',t.tag_bg,'</a>') from tags t where t.id=s.tag3) tag_3
from software where...
```

and then inside the fetch_assoc():

```
<tr><td class='software'><div class='tags'>Tags:</div>" . $rowsoft['tag_1'] . "" . $rowsoft['tag_2'] . "" . $rowsoft['tag_3'] . "</td></tr>
```

Works great, thanks for advises!

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude them from the query as @Musa says. That's probably the best way as the DB is doing the work. You can also do with a bunch of if statements testing if $rowsoft['tag_1'] is null then don't do the echo.